# How do I disambiguate associated types?

Tags: rust, associated-types

My current code looks like this:

```
pub trait A {}
pub trait HasA {
    type A: A;
    fn gimme_a() -> Self::A;
}

pub trait RichA: A {}
pub trait RichHasA: HasA {
    type A: RichA;
    fn gimme_a() -> Self::A;
    // ... more things go here ...
}

pub fn main() {}
```

My goal is to be able to use `RichHasA` as a `HasA`. The above code fails to compile with:

```
error[E0221]: ambiguous associated type `A` in bounds of `Self`
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
3  |     type A: A;
   |     ---------- ambiguous `A` from `HasA`
...
9  |     type A: RichA;
   |     -------------- ambiguous `A` from `RichHasA`
10 |     fn gimme_a() -> Self::A;
   |                     ^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type `A`
```

which makes sense. How can I  disambiguate associated types?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use what is called [*Fully Qualified Syntax*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) (FQS):

```
fn gimme_a() -> <Self as HasA>::A;
fn gimme_a() -> <Self as RichHasA>::A;
```

See also:

- [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same method name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445730/155423)