# How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same method name?

Tags: rust

This program dies because of infinite recursion:

```
use std::any::Any;

trait Foo {
    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Any>;
}

impl Foo for Vec<i32> {
    fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Any> {
        Vec::get(self, index).map(|v| v as &Any)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 4];
    println!("Results: {:?}", v.get(0))
}
```

The compiler itself warns about this:

```
warning: function cannot return without recurring
  --> src/main.rs:8:5
   |
8  |       fn get(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Any> {
   |  _____^ starting here...
9  | |         Vec::get(self, index).map(|v| v as &Any)
10 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
   |
   = note: #[warn(unconditional_recursion)] on by default
note: recursive call site
  --> src/main.rs:9:9
   |
9  |         Vec::get(self, index).map(|v| v as &Any)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = help: a `loop` may express intention better if this is on purpose
```

Why does universal call syntax not work in this case? The compiler does not understand that I want to call `Vec::get` not `Foo::get`.

How can I fix this, if I do not want to change function names?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To specify which method to call, whether inherent or provided from a trait, you want to use the [*fully qualified syntax*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name):

```
Type::function(maybe_self, needed_arguments, more_arguments)
Trait::function(maybe_self, needed_arguments, more_arguments)
```

Your case doesn't work because `Vec` *doesn't have a method called `get`*! `get` is provided from the [`Deref` implementation to `[T]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#deref-methods).

The easiest fix is to call `as_slice` directly:

```
self.as_slice().get(index).map(|v| v as &Any)
```

You could also use the fully qualified syntax which requires the angle brackets in this case (`<...>`) to avoid ambiguity with declaring an array literal:

```
<[i32]>::get(self, index).map(|v| v as &Any)
```

---

> universal call syntax

Note that while Rust originally used the term universal function call syntax (UFCS), the usage of this term conflicted with the existing understood programming term, so the use of it is not suggested. The replacement term is fully qualified syntax.

Comment: If it is `Deref`, should `<Vec<i32> as Deref>::get(self, index)` also do the trick?

Comment: @user1244932 an interesting question, but it doesn't appear so. The whole point of this syntax is to be unambiguous, so `<T as Deref>` would mean "only the methods on the `Deref` trait", but `get` isn't such a method.

Comment: Note that when using the `<T>::foo` syntax to pay attention to whether the impl providing `foo` is on `T` or `&T` or `&mut T`. I spent a bunch of time trying to figure out why inside by impl on `&mut [u8]` I couldn't call the builtin slice `len` method with `<&mut [u8]>::len` which was just picking up my own `len` method. I needed `<[u8]>::len`.