# Can I alias fully qualified syntax?

Tags: syntax, rust, type-alias

I have some code where I have many instances of fully qualified syntax; as an example:

```
mod hal {
    pub trait Backend {
        type Device;
    }
}

mod back {
    pub struct Backend {}

    impl ::hal::Backend for Backend {
        type Device = i32;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d: back::Backend::Device = 0;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=710159b24866cf75bff623947e57bbb4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

In order to avoid errors like:

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
  --> src/main.rs:16:12
   |
16 |     let d: back::Backend::Device = 0;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type
   |
   = note: specify the type using the syntax `<back::Backend as Trait>::Device`
```

Is there a nice way in which I can alias `SomeType as SomeTrait`? Then, wherever this instance of fully qualified syntax is needed, I can write:

`<S>::associated_fn(...)`

Note that this error does not occur because there are actually multiple implementations of some trait's definition (which is what FQS is supposed to handle, according to *The Rust Programming Language*).

Comment: Why do you have "many instances of fully qualified syntax" to start with?

Comment: @Shepmaster I am using a library called `gfx-rs`, which has something called `hal` (hardware abstraction layer). `hal` is really a bunch of traits, and these traits are implemented by platform specific backends (e.g. vulkan, directx, etc.). Thus, I often have to write `<gfx_vulkan::backend::Backend as hal::Backend>::some_fn`, in order to get to the implementation of some particular function.

Comment: None of that indicates why you have to use FQS instead of just calling the methods directly. Are there multiple traits defining `some_fn`?

Comment: @Shepmaster This is something I do not quite understand about the library, because it seems to me that `hal` does not implement multiple traits defining some associated function, or type...however, the compiler complains about receiving an ambiguous type when FQS is left out. I have included an example of the error in the question now.

Comment: @Shepmaster so i was able to confirm that the error occurs not because there are multiple impls of some definition; here is a minimal example that reproduces the same error (courtesy of someone on the project's gitter): https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=710159b24866cf75bff623947e57bbb4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Answer (score 4):

In your example, you can rename some of the parts so you can refer to them without conflicts in the shortened form:

```
use hal::Backend;
use back::Backend as BackendImpl;

fn main() {
    let d: <BackendImpl as Backend>::Device = 0;
}
```

You may also consider defining a type alias, which is less ambiguous to access:

```
mod hal {
    pub trait Backend {
        type Device;
    }
}

mod back {
    pub struct Backend {}
    pub type Device = i32;
    impl ::hal::Backend for Backend {
        type Device = Device;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d: back::Device = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to alias the fully-qualified syntax. Doing so doesn't make sense to me as the whole *point* of this syntax is to be completely unambiguous.

---

All of this assumes that you actually need fully-qualified syntax. As the name indicates, there's usually shorter ways of writing the code. These are all equivalent if no other traits defining `to_string` are in scope and the type itself doesn't implement a method of the same name:

```
<i32 as ToString>::to_string(&42);
```

```
ToString::to_string(&42);
```

```
i32::to_string(&42);
```

```
42.to_string();
```

See also:

- [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445730/155423)
- [How do I disambiguate traits in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44953197/155423)

Comment: so in OP's example you could just write `gfx_vulkan::backend::Backend::some_fn();` ?

Comment: @Rots no, it doesn't seem like you can, i have added a MnWE to the question now

Comment: That [works with functions](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=791a7c33e12203a3a17d18e2994db217&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015) but apparently not with associated types.