# How to call n.(Y::f)() in Rust if n is type Box<dyn Y>, Y is a subtrait of X and both X and Y has function f()

Tags: rust, traits

The following code fails to compile because both `X` and `Y` have a function `x()`.
`X::f(&n)` doesn't work because `n` is type `Box<dyn Y>`.

How to call `n.(Y::f)()` in this situation?

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba8836e793db6540c01b4fef35f70c40))

```
trait X {
    fn f(&self) {
        println!("x")
    }
}
trait Y: X {
    fn f(&self) {
        println!("y")
    }
}

impl X for u32 {}
impl Y for u32 {}

fn main() {
    let n: Box<dyn Y> = Box::new(1);
    println!("{:?}", n.f());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disambiguate traits in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953197/how-do-i-disambiguate-traits-in-rust)

Comment: "*X::f(&n) doesn't work because n is type Box*"—so deref it `X::f(&*n)` ?

Comment: X::f(&*n) works! thanks. I didn't know Box<dyn Trait> can be deref in this way.

Comment: `X::f(n.as_ref())` would also work if you find `&*` a bit too magical (as I do).

Comment: Don't do this. This looks like you are trying to do something class-like where `f` in the subclass overrides `f` in the superclass. Traits aren't classes and don't work that way. There should never be any reason for a trait to have a method named the same as another method in a supertrait.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0f7bcdb6fd831bdd28a92e61b34646bb This one?