# Implementing traits without repeating methods already defined on the struct

Tags: struct, rust, traits

I have a trait which only has one requirement, the presence of a methods `len(&self) -> usize`. It then provides implementations for a couple of new methods for the struct.

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;

    // ... some new functions with implementations
}
```

I'd like to implement this trait on `std::collections::LinkedList` which already has a method with that exact type signature. Currently, I'm doing this:

```
impl<T> MyTrait for LinkedList<T> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }
}
```

I can then use the new methods defined by `MyTrait` on my `LinkedList` instances. However, it feels unnecessary to have to repeat the definition of the method like this, since the type signatures are identical. Is there a way to omit the re-definition of `len` in my trait implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to omit the re-definition of `len` in my trait implementation?

No, it is not possible.

You may be able to write a macro of some kind to write the code for you, but dealing with type parameters is annoying, to say the least.

See also:

- [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445730/155423)

Comment: Ah OK; thank you for your answer. I'd consider writing a macro if I needed to implement this trait more, but since it'll only be for `LinkedList` I won't bother. Thanks again