# How to use turbofish operator for generic trait implementation

Tags: rust, traits

I have below generic trait:

```
trait A<T> {
    fn foo(&self) -> T;
}
```

I have following struct which implements trait `A` for `String` and `usize`:

```
struct S;

impl A<String> for S {
    fn foo(&self) -> String {
        String::from("Hello world")
    }
}

impl A<usize> for S {
    fn foo(&self) -> usize {
        37
    }
}
```

When I call method `foo`, I can specify type to the variable and that works:

```
let value: usize = s.foo();
```

But how can I do the same thing with turbofish operator?

I tried following without success:

```
let text = s::<usize>.foo();
let text = s.foo::<usize>();
let text = s.::<usize>foo();
```

How do I use this operator instead of providing the type to the variable?

Comment: What does the Rust reference documentation say about this operator?

Comment: [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same method name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445730/how-to-call-a-method-when-a-trait-and-struct-use-the-same-method-name) is also related. (The dupe applied to this question: `A::<usize>::foo(&s)`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this, because the "turbofish" operator is syntax for specifying generic parameters to *something*, but your method is not generic, even though it is defined in a generic trait, so there are no generic parameters to specify.

What you can do is to use the [fully qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) to explicitly name the trait, which *is* generic:

```
let text = A::<usize>::foo(&s);
```

Comment: Perfection . Thanks