# How can I create a trait for the inherent methods of a type I don't own?

Tags: rust

I'd like to implement my own version of a Rust standard library feature and use my version and the real standard library version interchangeably.

If the standard library feature were a trait, this would be easy. However, the standard library feature (in this case, [`std::sync::Condvar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html)) is implemented as

```
pub struct Condvar {...}

impl Condvar {...}
```

I tried doing

```
impl Condvar for MyCondvar {...}
```

but got an error ("error[E0404]: expected trait, found struct `Condvar`")

How should I do this? I've also tried

```
pub trait CondvarTrait { // copy entire interface of Condvar }

impl CondvarTrait for Condvar {
  // copy entire interface of Condvar again,
  // implementing foo(&self, ...) by calling self.foo(...)
}

impl CondvarTrait for MyCondvar { // my own implementation }
```

which compiles, but is super verbose. Is there a better way?

Comment: Just an idea: make two versions of your library. One defines your types. The other just re-exports the standard types.

Comment: I think, without new Rust features or some macro magic, the latter example is the only way to do it. There's no way to turn a struct into a trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the entire interface of the type and reimplement it by calling the inherent methods.

See also:

- [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same method name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445730/155423)

> Is there a better way?

Not with how you've described the requirements.

That being said, you aren't introducing any abstraction suited to your domain. In many cases, you don't want the full power of the underlying type(s), but want to do some higher-level abstraction. If you create *that* abstraction as a trait, then you can implement the new trait for any useful types.