# How to call an associated function implemented for &str?

Tags: rust, serde

I am trying to write a custom `Deserialize` implementation that can perform a case insensitive deserialization of my enum:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.120
use serde_json; // 1.0.61

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum MyEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar,
}

// Implements case-insensitive deserialization of node types using from_str above
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for MyEnum {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let v = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        match v.to_ascii_lowercase().as_ref() {
            "foo" => Ok(MyEnum::Foo),
            "bar" => Ok(MyEnum::Bar),
            _ => Err(serde::de::Error::custom("invalid value")),
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but results in two allocations: one to place the input value into a `String` and another to convert that `String` to uppercase. I don't need the first one because serde provides an implementation of [`Deserialize for &str`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.123/serde/de/trait.Deserialize.html#impl-Deserialize%3C%27de%3E-for-%26%27a%20str). How do I call that?

This does not work:

```rust
let v: &str = &str::deserialize(deserializer)?
```

because:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:16:24
    |
16  |         let v: &str = &str::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `str`
    | 
   ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.120/src/de/mod.rs:540:12
    |
540 |         D: Deserializer<'de>;
    |            ----------------- required by this bound in `serde::Deserialize::deserialize`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <&'a str as Deserialize<'de>>
```

(in addition to other errors about the size of str not being known).

It even tells me there is an implementation for `&'a str`, but I am unsure what syntax to use to call it.

Comment: See also [How to call a method when a trait and struct use the same method name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44445730/155423).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

harmic provided a "dispatch" via the output type, you can invoke the method on the trait itself as long as the result is disambiguated.

Alternatively, you can use a "turbofish" in order to force a type-evaluation: as the error tells you, `&str::deserialize(deserializer)?` really parses as `&(str::deserialize(deserializer)?)`. `<&str>::deserialize(deserializer)?` will force the call to happen on `&str` instead, and obviate the need for explicitly typing the result.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I eventually found (and I am not sure it is the only one) is to call the method on the trait, and use a type annotation to ensure the correct one is chosen.

```rust
let v : &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
```