# Rust md5::digest::Digest::digest cannot infer type for format!(...).as_bytes()

Tags: rust

I'm trying to take a simple MD5 digest:

```
let a1_part1 = md5::digest::Digest::digest(format!("{}:{}:{}", username, realm, password).as_bytes());
```

But I get this error:

```
102 |             let a1_part1 = md5::digest::Digest::digest(format!("{}:{}:{}", username, realm, password).as_bytes());
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
```

I don't know which type it's referring about. `format!` returns a `String`, and `as_bytes` returns `&[u8]` as you see: `pub fn as_bytes(&self) -> &[u8]`.

What is wrong?

This is the crate being used: https://crates.io/crates/md-5

Comment: Can you build a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to clarify the question (most especially your imports) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that `Digest` is a trait, re-exported from the md-5 crate but actually defined in the [`digest`](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/index.html) crate.

The `digest` function in this trait is defined like this:

```
fn digest(data: &[u8]) -> Output<Self>
```

There are two things to notice here. First, it is an associated function, rather than a method, so it does not take a `self` argument. Second, the return value is defined in terms of `Self`, the type implementing the trait.

This is the origin of the `cannot infer type` error: the compiler is unable to figure out the type of `Self` since you are calling the function directly from the trait.

You can specify the type using the 'turbofish' operator, like so:

```
use md5::{Md5, Digest};

let a1_part1 = <Md5>::digest(format!("{}:{}:{}", username, realm, password).as_bytes());
```

See also: [How to call an associated function implemented for &str?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988743/how-to-call-an-associated-function-implemented-for-str)